# MATLAB avi file read

Tags: matlab, ffmpeg

Is there a way to read .avi video file frame by frame using mmread or other function, similar to using videoReader, and readFrame functions?
I used mmread but it took a long time to read each frame as it read all the frames before the specified frame.

Comment: If your goal is to skip many frames, you may have better luck with the regular `read` function (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreader.read.html) It allows you to specify the frames you want to read

Answer (score 0):

In general the media and movie reading in Matlab is cumbersome. I changed to python because of it. I would recommend to split the movie into single image files using tools like avconv or ffmpg and then work on the images, as the image manipulation toolbox is much faster.

If you want to go forward and backward through any movie, especially backwards is very slow. Very often it is implemented, by rewinding and than seeking out your frame, so basically to go from frame  100 to 99, Matlab rewinds to 0 and  then seeks through the binary stuff to 99.

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
Actually, I don't need to go backward. I only need to read forward frame by frame. But if I use, let's say,
for i = 1:num
mmread('target.avi', i)
end
it takes very long time as the count number increases. I wonder if there is something similar to videoReader function.

Comment: My videos are very long, so I'm tempted not to split them into images. But I will think about this option as well. Thank you.